# phonegap CSS not rendering properly in IOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I am trying to create a simple application using phone gap ,but it seems css is not rendering as expected in the phone gap in IOS for buttons
In browser the button displays as expected ,but in phonegap the style displayed differently.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Counter V 1.0</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/counter.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1><a id="clicks">0</a></h1>           
<div class="half">
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="increase-button" onClick="increase()">    
    <input type="submit" value="-" class="decrease-button" onClick="decrease()">                            
</div>   
 <div class="half">
 <p><input type="submit" value="Reset" class="reset-button" onClick="reset()"></p>          
</div>
</body>
</html>

![enter image description here][1]Counter.css
.increase-button{
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 50%;
 height: 60px;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 background: #27ae60;
 border: 0; 
 }

.decrease-button{
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 50%;
 height: 60px;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 background: #e74c3c;
 border: 0;
 }

.reset-button{
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 50%;
 height: 60px;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 background: #3498db;
 border: 0;
 }
```

Comment: You need to use CSS properties that are compatible with iOS webviews (not the same as the browser on the device).

Comment: Can you please confirm that you get any of the css properties counter.css reflected in your web page. Try simply adding `background-color:red` to any of the visible component and confirm that yiur custom.css is attached properly to your webpage if not that is your issue

Comment: yes height ,width is getting reflected properly but the back ground and shape of the button is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to replicate what you have mentioned here. I was able to get the perfect result. For the same i have attached the image as under. Is this what you are expecting ?

[image: Your output]

You can download the project at [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6XmF7J4fwmIREt3N1pQdXRaMVE/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT :**

Here is the solution

update your css to this

```
.increase-button{
position: relative;
vertical-align: top;
width: 50%;
height: 60px;
padding: 0;
font-size: 40px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
background: #27ae60;
border: 0;
width: 50%;
height: 60px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.decrease-button{
position: relative;
vertical-align: top;
width: 50%;
height: 60px;
padding: 0;
font-size: 22px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
background: #e74c3c;
border: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0px !important;

}

.reset-button{
position: relative;
vertical-align: top;
width: 50%;
height: 60px;
padding: 0;
font-size: 22px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
background: #3498db;
border: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0px !important;

}
```

Reason was uiwebview was adding additional  -webkit-appearance:pushbutton and border-radius:20px which i have override in last two lines of css.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not the expected button style , if you open the same css in browser you will see a flat design button.

Comment: I have edited the answer kindly check at your end. The reason was the cordova's webview was adding additional stylesheets in your code based on input, button and submit buttons we need to override those style to achieve the results. If the answer is upto your expectation you can vote up cheers :)

Comment: My issue got resolved when i gave <button> tag instead of <input> tag..Thanks for the time

Comment: You can check this css in the edit it will also solve your issue. As the phonegap webview apply its own style to inputs. We can avoid it by overriding them. I have checked the same at my end. And if the answer is useful you can accept the answer.